# Dependency isuue installing: libmagickwand-dev

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg, dependencies

I'm trying to download imagick for my ubuntu machine, I tried command:

```
sudo apt-get install pkg-config libmagickwand-dev -y
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
pkg-config is already the newest version (0.29.1-0ubuntu2).
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

**The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmagickwand-dev : Depends: libmagickwand-6.q16-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.**
```

Comment: Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll notice only *standard* supported releases of Ubuntu and flavors are on-topic for this site.  Your pasted package versions only match EOL or EOSS releases of Ubuntu

Comment: The use of apt's `-y` is discouraged in this kind of circumstance. It means "*do it regardless of the consequences without a chance to review or cancel*." Your system seems a mess -- you should be using that opportunity to review.